# Generic table issue in angular-8

Tags: angular8

Generic table (gt column setting) attribute is not working in angular and (gt Search) is not working as well

Throwing this error on hitting this command

```
npm i @angular-generic-table/column-settings
```

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-generic-table/column-settings/fesm5/angular-generic-table-column-settings.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-dragula' in 'E:\Workspace\Retegrity\Source\WebRetegrity\webretegrity\node_modules@angular-generic-table\column-settings\fesm5'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-generic-table/core/fesm5/angular-generic-table-core.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tether' in 'E:\Workspace\Retegrity\Source\WebRetegrity\webretegrity\node_modules@angular-generic-table\core\fesm5'